# Hockeyapp - Please make sure that the versionCode is 1 or higher

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

Trying to upload a Xamarin build to Hockeyapp I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading to Hockeyapp, don't select an existing app name from a prior upload you did for another platform, choose to "create new application".

Now, it's worth mentioning you can use the same app name as a previous app, here's how I did it.  I had already created an Android version of my app called MyApp within HockeyApp, when I tried to upload the UWP project I tried to select the previous app name from the dropdown titled "MyApp".  You can't do this.  Instead, I went into my project properties for my UWP app, then clicked on "Package Manifest" then click on Packaging and changed the "Package Display Name" to the same, in my case that was "MyApp".